# Bokeh bar coloring by data

Tags: python, colors, bokeh

I want to give a different color to my bar if the data
I have two list filled with values.

I need to compore one to the other.

If A list index0 value is more than B list index0 value by 10%, than color that bar with red.

```
for i in avg_list:
    s = float(i) * 0.1
    print(s)
    for n in min_list:
        d = int(i) - int(n)
        if int(d) > int(s):
            color ='red' 
        else:
            color = 'lightskyblue'
            
p.vbar(
    x=dodge('x',0.2, range=p.x_range),
    top='AVG',
    width = 0.38,
    fill_color= color,
    source=cds,
    legend_label="AVG",
)
```

Comment: There are directly relevant examples in the documentation: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/basic/bars.html#filling

Comment: I was able to solve it after two hours I asked. Thanks!